# Mocking Http-503 for a web service

Tags: web-services, mocking, soapui, osb

I would like to mock a web service response for an HTTP 503 (Error 503--Service Unavailable) when The server is unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. What is the best strategy?
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I use:

https://httpstat.us/503

No external software or dependencies required.

Comment: Perfect answer. Didn't know that was a thing. Thanks!

Comment: I really like this answer, I was searching exactly this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Groovy script:

```
mockRequest.getHttpResponse().sendError(503)
```

Answer (score 2):

the use : https://designer.mocky.io/ for test 503 http request

Comment: Good start for helping out in answering this question! Your answer could be a bit better if it provided an example of how to use the tool. Maybe provide a basic example?

Answer (score 1):

Use xml mimic, you can mock almost everything with http response without the need for real server.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlmimic/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlmimic/